# How to store javascript timer countdown for quiz that don't reset

Tags: javascript, php, time, timer

I need help for storing time for this timer countdown it's running OK but when I press refresh or back of the browser the timer will start it over again like 15:00 then the timer start   example the time is 9:00 if I press the refresh it will go back to 15:00.

```js
(function() {

    function display(notifier, str) {
      document.getElementById(notifier).innerHTML = str;
    }

    function toMinuteAndSecond(x) {
      return ~~(x / 60) + ":" + (x % 60 < 10 ? "0" : "") + x % 60;
    }

    function setTimer(remain, actions) {
      var action;
      (function countdown() {
        display("countdown", toMinuteAndSecond(remain));
        if (action = actions[remain]) {
          action();
        }
        if (remain > 0) {
          remain -= 1;
          setTimeout(arguments.callee, 1000);
        }
      })(); // End countdown
    }
    setTimer(900, {
        120: function() {
          display("notifier", "Just 1 minute to go");
        },
        50: function() {
          display("notifier", "50 seconds left");
        },

      }
    }
  );
})();
```

```html
<span id="notifier"></span>
```

Comment: So store start time in session on PHP and when page loads use the time to caculate how much time is remaining.

Comment: Some sensible code indentation would be a good idea. It helps us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: I created a snippet and get a syntax error in the console. Please fix

Comment: hello sir epascarello thanks how about doing it on javascript?

Answer (score 0):

In JS -  note where I put the localStorage (which does not run in a snippet)
I also fixed the errors in the posted code

```js
(function() {

  function display(notifier, str) {
    document.getElementById(notifier).innerHTML = str;
  }

  function toMinuteAndSecond(x) {
    return ~~(x / 60) + ":" + (x % 60 < 10 ? "0" : "") + x % 60;
  }

  function setTimer(remain, actions) {
    var action;
    (function countdown() {
      // add localStorage.setItem("countdown",remain)
      display("countdown", toMinuteAndSecond(remain));
      if (action = actions[remain]) {
        action();
      }
      if (remain > 0) {
        remain -= 1;
        setTimeout(arguments.callee, 1000);
      }
      else display("countdown","Done");
    })(); // End countdown
  }
  setTimer(30, { // change 30 to +localStorage.getItem("countdown") || 30;
    20: function() {
      display("countdown", "Just 20 seconds to go");
    },
    10: function() {
      display("countdown", "10 seconds left");
    },
  });
})();
```

```html
<span id="countdown"></span>
```

Comment: it's working thank you my only problem now is how to make it start it again hehe thanks a lot sir mplungjan

Comment: how rerun the timer again if they want to quiz again

Comment: `<input type="button" onclick="localStorage.setItem('countdown',900); location.reload()" />`

Answer (score -1):

Here we should keep variable `remain` in local storage. variables in local storage will be available even after refresh.

Attaching the code which will work as expected for you.

```
(function() {

    function display(notifier, str) {
      document.getElementById(notifier).innerHTML = str;
    }

    function toMinuteAndSecond(x) {
      return ~~(x / 60) + ":" + (x % 60 < 10 ? "0" : "") + x % 60;
    }

    function setTimer(remain, actions) {
      var action;
      localStorage.remain = remain;
      (function countdown() {
        remain =  localStorage.remain;
        display("countdown", toMinuteAndSecond(remain));
        if (action = actions[remain]) {
          action();
        }
        if (remain > 0) {
          localStorage.remain -= 1;
          setTimeout(arguments.callee, 1000);
        }
      })(); // End countdown
    }
    setTimer(900, {
        120: function() {
          display("notifier", "Just 1 minute to go");
        },
        50: function() {
          display("notifier", "50 seconds left");
        },

      }
    }
  );
})();
```